# Sublime Text 2 on OS X Lion not finding git binary in PATH

Tags: git, osx-lion, integration, sublimetext2

I'm just getting started with my dev environment on OS X Lion and recently installed Sublime Text 2 and git integration using Package Control. So, when I press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> I get all the relevant git commands.

However, whenever I use one, I get the same error message: [sublime-git-error](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1261638/Screen%20Shot%202012-06-10%20at%2012.19.21%20AM.png)

Here's what I've done to try and fix it:

I ran `mdfind -name git` in terminal and noticed that all the binaries from my git install (v. 1.7.10.3) are located in `/usr/local/git/bin` so I tried editing `~/.profile` with this line:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:usr/local/lib;/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

and when I run `echo $PATH` now in terminal the directory is listed there.

Even so, I still get the same error message as above. Any solutions or pointing out what I'm missing are appreciated!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Basically you need to set

```
"git_command": "/usr/local/git/bin/git"
```

in Packages/User/Git.sublime-settings 
or in Packages/Git/Git.sublime-settings

For more details have a look at this issue => https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-git/issues/96

Comment: Worked for me too. I didn't have the `Git.sublime_settings` file so had to create it and everything worked on restart

Comment: Just to point out that if you have installed git via homebrew then you'll need to set this to `"git_command": "/usr/local/bin/git"` as that is the location Homebrew symlinks it too. When I installed via Homebrew I removed the default Mac installation of git. It's much easy to manage everything with a package manager.

Comment: On OS X: subl "./Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Git/Git.sublime-settings"

Comment: Here is where to add on Mac: Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Package Settings > Git > User - Settings: user add { "git_command": "/usr/local/bin/git" }

Answer (score 2):

quoting directly from the link provided, I used a more recent fix that worked for me:

```
"git_command": "/usr/local/bin/"
```

best  of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (ST3 Mac):

1. Sublime Text > Preference > Browse Packages...
2. Open Users/Package Control.sublime-settings
3. Edit the `git_binary` value to be the path to your git. I got my git path by typing `which git` in a terminal window, then pasted that in.